# NeoVim Status Bar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, neovim

Im really new to Vim and stuff like that, and I want to see the status bar colorized, but its transparent. How can I change

```
hi StatusLine ctermbg=129 ctermfg=201
```

is not working

Comment: Can we see a screenshot, please? Just to be sure about what you call "Status Bar".

Comment: I cant because im in school but i think about the line that says --INSERT-- and thevlines and columns

Comment: That line is called "command line" and you can't colorise it. The part at the end that gives you some information about the current buffer is called "ruler", see `:help 'ruler'`. To get an actual "status line", the thing your snippet applies to, see `:help 'laststatus'` and `:help 'statusline'`. Last thing, Vim comes with an extremely well made built-in tutorial: `:help user-manual`.